# View layout made with Bulma is not being displayed as expected on the phone

Tags: html, css, iphone, frontend, bulma

I have a web-app made by using `Bulma + Django`.Everything looks fine in the browser and it also does when I shrink the browser. It work as I expected.

Then I used `ngrok` to test the view from a real phone and here is the problem.

**On the phone the view looks "small", like zoomed out, it is not looking like the desktop browser version**.

Here is a picture showing the difference:
[image]

How can I make the phone version to look like the desktop shrinked one? What am I missing in the code? I tried using the `is-mobile` class, but it didn't work.

**Here is my HTML code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  <title>Testing Bulma</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section container">

    <h1 class="title is-1">Testing Bulma!</h1>
    <h2 class="title is-2">Seems cool!</h2>
    <h2 class="subtitle">A Subtitle</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <div class="control">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input">
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button is-info">Info</button>
      <button class="button is-success">Success</button>
      <button class="button is-warning">Warning</button>
      <button class="button is-danger">Danger</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your head-part:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

This gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.